# Spring MVC @GetMapping produces json and excel

Tags: excel, angular, spring

I have a problem in Spring MVC @GetMapping annotation with produces. 
Background: I designed API that always response in the following structure

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private T data;
    private Map<String, String> extraInfo;

    ... constructor / getter / setter
}
```

I have an Angular 8 client that consumes this api response.

---

I am going to design a method to send excel byte[] using this structure. (due to some reason, I cannot use HttpServletResponse like other tutorials found in Google)

First, when sending data with simple object, I can use

```
@GetMapping(value="/getObject", produces="application/json")
public ApiResponse<MyObject> sendObject(){
    Map<String, String> extraInfo = new HashMap<>();
    extraInfo.put("some", "thing");

    return new ApiResponse(myObject, extraInfo);
}
```

My Angular client can read this format correctly.

In addition, when sending excel byte[] alone, I can use

```
@GetMapping(value="/getExcel", produces="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
public byte[] sendExcelByteArray(){
    return myExcelByteArray;
}
```

My Angular client is able to convert the byte[] into excel file correctly (file can be opened normally)

But I have a problem. When I am going to use

```
@GetMapping(value="/getObject", produces="application/json")
public ApiResponse<byte[]> sendObject(){
    Map<String, String> extraInfo = new HashMap<>();
    extraInfo.put("some", "thing");

    return new ApiResponse(myExcelByteArray, extraInfo);
}
```

in either "application/json" or "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

My Angular client cannot read the excel data (it said the file is corrupted).

Are there any approaches, I can use ApiResponse to "wrap" my excel byte[] that Angular client can convert normally?

Comment: You can base64 encode it, send it, and then manually decode it and write it. Probably, but it requires work on the client side. It is much easier to directly write the response.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it. Because my backend used Spring Cloud and highly used Feign. It does not support HttpServletResponse to download a file. Therefore I tried to work around.